# why label pack gives an error when it is not used separately

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

when I use this code to change the color of the window and the label, everything goes great '

```py
import tkinter
from tkinter.colorchooser import askcolor

photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="something.png")
label = tkinter.Label(
    window,
    text="this is a label",
    image=photo,
    compound='bottom'
)

label.pack(ipadx=0, ipady=0)

def change_color():
    colors = askcolor(title="Tkinter Color Chooser")
    window.configure(bg=colors[1])
    label.configure(bg=colors[1])

ttk = tkinter.Button(
    window,
    text='Select a Color',
    command=change_color).pack(expand=True)
```

but if I add the `.pack()` to the first label declaration, and I try to change the color it returns error

```py
label = tkinter.Label(
        window,
        text="this is a label",
        image=photo,
        compound='bottom'
).pack(ipadx=0, ipady=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

A common mistake by beginners. Move the `.pack()` onto a separate line because you have to assign the variable to the label object and not to the `.pack` method which return `None`. So do this  -

```
label = tkinter.Label(
        window,
        text="this is a label",
        image=photo,
        compound='bottom'
    )
label.pack(ipadx=0, ipady=0)
```